# Is it possible to install Windows 10 on vSphere 5.0?

Tags: windows-10, bsod, vsphere

I've tried installing Windows 10 on a vSphere 5.0 hypervisor but it hangs on first boot with BSOD and a MEMORY MANAGEMENT stop code. After searching for this only fixes for more recent vSphere versions like 5.1 show up. I can't upgrade the hypervisor now due to availability restrictions.

I've followed this KB which helped me before for Win 2012R2 installs without success: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2060019

I've also tried installing it in a recent vSphere version specifying compatibility with vSphere 5.0 and migrating the files to the older hypervisor (with ovf and also copying the entire vm folder) but still no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like that isn't supported:  [VMware Guest OS Compatibility Guide](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/pdf/VMware_GOS_Compatibility_Guide.pdf), as well as [Supported host operating systems for vSphere Client](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2100436)

Comment: You are aware of the fact that VSphere 5.0, has pratically zero support from VMWare, at this point right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried installing Windows 10 on a vSphere 5.0 hypervisor but it hangs on first boot with BSOD and a MEMORY MANAGEMENT stop code.

ESXi/VSphere 5.0 does not support Windows 10 VMs.

[image]

[image]

> Any thoughts?

You should upgrade to a compatible version of VSphere.  The only alternative to that is to run a compatiable version of Windows that VSphere 5.0 supports.

Sources:

- [Supported host operating systems for vSphere Client (Windows) installation (2100436)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2100436)
- [VMWare Compatibility Guide](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/pdf/VMware_GOS_Compatibility_Guide.pdf)